# Change button url according to selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have the following problem. I have JSP with the following code

```
<c:forEach var="player" items="${gridItems}" varStatus="loopCounter">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${player.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${player.nickname}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${player.gamesPlayed}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${player.eloPoints}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${player.rank}" /></td>
                <td><div class="input-field col s12">
                        <select id="mode">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Game mode</option>
                            <option value="1">Blitz</option>
                            <option value="2">10 minutes</option>
                            <option value="3">30 minutes</option>
                            <option value="4">60 minutes</option>
                        </select> <label>Choose game mode</label>
                    </div></td>
                <td class="right"><a class="btn-floating"
                    href="${pagesPlayer}/${player.id}"><i class="material-icons">info</i></a>
                    <a class="btn-floating green tooltipped disabled" id="test" data-field="${player.id}"
                    data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="<spring:message code="play.against" />"><i
                        class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i></a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
        $('select').formSelect();
    });
        $(document).on('change','#mode',function() {
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        $('#test').attr('href',"${contextPath}/play/make_game/?white_player_id=${loggedUserId}&black_player_id="
                                +$('#test').attr('data-field')+"&mode="+ value);
                    });
        $("#mode").on('change',function() {
                $("#test").addClass("floating green tooltipped").removeClass('disabled');
            });

</script>
```

So at the web page, I have a table with the list of players, which I get from my controller (this is "griditems") and in every row, I have a selector and a button. The button is disabled until u choose an option in the selector.
I need to change the URL of this button according to the selected option and enable this button.
This code works only if I have one row. I choose an option, button enabled and I can click the button with URL.
But if I have 2 rows or more this works only the first row in the table, when I choose the option in the selector in the second-row button in the second row is still disabled.
I need to enable button in the row if in this row option in the selector is chosen and link button in this row according to the selected option. There could be 10 rows for a page and in every row, I need to implement this logic. How can I do that?

Comment: You're repeating the `mode` and `test` ids.  That is invalid markup.  Those should be classes instead.

Comment: @Taplar, can you show some example, I' m pretty new to front-end development so I don't undestand well what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `class` instead of `id` and then use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.test')` to find the class with name `test` which needed to be changed on the same row.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
  $('select').formSelect();
});
$(document).on('change', '.mode', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  //select-box (this)-><tr>->find class with name=test
  var $selector = $(this).closest('tr').find('.test');
  var url = $selector.attr('href', "${contextPath}/play/make_game/?white_player_id=${loggedUserId}&black_player_id=" +
    $selector.attr('data-field') + "&mode=" + value);
  console.log($selector.attr('data-field'));
});
$(".mode").on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.test').addClass("floating green tooltipped").removeClass('disabled');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Abc</td>
    <td>Cricket</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select class="mode">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Game mode</option>
          <option value="1">Blitz</option>
          <option value="2">10 minutes</option>
          <option value="3">30 minutes</option>
          <option value="4">60 minutes</option>
        </select> <label>Choose game mode</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="right"><a class="btn-floating" href="${pagesPlayer}/1"><i class="material-icons">info</i></a>
      <!-- here i have given class="test"-->
      <a class="btn-floating green tooltipped disabled test" data-field="1" id="test" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="SOMETHING"><i
                        class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Ab2</td>
    <td>Footabll</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select class="mode">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Game mode</option>
          <option value="1">Blitz</option>
          <option value="2">10 minutes</option>
          <option value="3">30 minutes</option>
          <option value="4">60 minutes</option>
        </select> <label>Choose game mode</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="right"><a class="btn-floating" href="${pagesPlayer}/2"><i class="material-icons">info</i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating green tooltipped disabled test" data-field="2" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="SOMETHING"><i
                        class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Abc3</td>
    <td>Chess</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select class="mode">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Game mode</option>
          <option value="1">Blitz</option>
          <option value="2">10 minutes</option>
          <option value="3">30 minutes</option>
          <option value="4">60 minutes</option>
        </select> <label>Choose game mode</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="right"><a class="btn-floating" href="${pagesPlayer}/3"><i class="material-icons">info</i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating green tooltipped disabled test" data-field="3" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="SOMETHING"><i
                        class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```